# Sqlite insert does not work (quietly) under android 6.0

Tags: android, sqlite, insert, android-sqlite

Sorry for my English, I'm a follower of the Google translator sect.

Strange behavior is completely banal code. On devices with android below 6.0 it works as expected. Works on an emulator with API23. But on the real device (on several different models) with android 6.0 inserted data can not be read back.

```
      try {
            long insertResult = db.insert(ibLocalBase.Tables.PhotoHeaders.TableName, null, valuesHeaders);
            insertResult = db.insert(ibLocalBase.Tables.PhotoBodies.TableName, null, valuesBodies);

            db.setTransactionSuccessful();

        } finally {
            db.endTransaction();
        }
```

Transaction is successful. insertResult has nice value (identical).
But later - i can get my data in PhotoHeaders, but nothing in PhotoBodies. Table PhotoBodies is empty! On android 6.0 device only!

Comment: Use `insertOrThrow()` instead.

Comment: **insertOrThrow()** works miraculously! Many thanks!

Comment: That should not have made any difference … 

Comment: As a result, I came to the conclusion that the size of the recorded data matters. And the size is large (photos should have been stored in the base - the customer's requirements). Reducing the size of images has solved the problem on all devices. This problem occurred on devices regardless of the OS version (antediluvian devices were not affected by this problem), but depended on the device manufacturer. The pure android always behaved right.

Answer (score -1):

Try using a SQL command, instead:

```
db.execSQL("insert into your table_name (data_one,data_two)" + "values("value_one+","+value_two+ "\"" + ") ;");
```